# Curiosity maths: names of non differentable points

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, reference-request, math-history

This is a rather for-the-sake-of-curiosity question.
I have studied the points in which a function might not be differentiable, and the most basic three cases are:

- Angular Point: when both left and right limits of the derivative in that point $p$ do exist (finite) but their values are different
- Cusp: when both left and right limits of the derivative in that point $p$ are infinite and their signs are opposite
- Inflection point at vertical tangent: when both left and right limits of the derivative in that point $p$ are infinite and of the same signs.

Now the question: are there USED OR MISUSED names for other types of non differentiable points? For example those cases:

- When one of the limits exists finite and the other is infinite (no matter of the sign)
- When one ot the limits exists finite and the other does not exist.
- When one of the limits is infinite and the other does not exist.

I have found, for the first one, that it can be called a **semi-cusp** point.

I am interested in knowing if other names / types are known in literature.

Comment: There can also be points where no limit exists.

Comment: @Mateo Indeed! I'm interested in possible names to call them. Weird request, perhaps, but why not?